# Would it be impolite to count money?

Tags: payment

Often times when I buy and sell using cash.

As a buyer I would count the money in front of the counterparty to ensure that the whole sum is present, or if I don't count it in front of them, I ask that the seller verify the sum when I hand the cash over.

However as a seller, I wonder if it would be impolite to count the buyer's monetary payment in front of them, signaling that I distrust them and need to verify the amount in question.

Chances are, I am reading too much into it.

Comment: This *really* borders on three reasons to close the question: off topic for PF, too broad, and opinion based.

Comment: I'll preemptively delete it if I see close votes. But at the same time, it is a cultural mannerism that directly impacts individuals and firms who handle cash money and needs to verify actual cash contents.

Comment: Do you have a retail store, or are you just talking about occasional situations where you are selling some belongings to someone else for cash?

Comment: I am not a commercial store, just in past experience (like selling a minifridge on craigslist, or buying a computer part on eBay and meeting in person)

Comment: @FrankFYC for what you mention, as the buyer, I'd count out the money as a show of openness/honesty.  As the buyer, I'd recount it to verify the buyer didn't do any sleight of hand...

Comment: This question would probably be on-topic at [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why not use a [currency-counting machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency-counting_machine)?

Answer (score 2):

IMNSHO "publicly" counting the money is an expression of *sunshine*: "it's my fiduciary mandate to ensure that you're doing right, and I'm proving to you that I'm not cheating you".

Comment: So the main limiter is impact on other people's transactions?

Comment: I'm not sure if "main" is the right word, because you've got to ensure that you don't overpay, and the cashier must ensure that you don't underpay (which is why I think I'm going to remove that first clause).  Still, don't be a dick and pay for something expensive with a pile of tiny bills...  :)

Comment: Like this guy? https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/man-pays-dmv-pennies_us_5879101ce4b0e58057fe80d7

Comment: No, because that's a "fighting City Hall" issue.  I'm talking about someone who goes to the store and buys $100 of groceries with $1 and $5 bills.

Comment: Some industries and professions compensate workers specifically with $1's and $5's. But I get the idea.

Comment: If you translate this to normal people language I will upvote you.